# grey line with no explanation in Java how to find the problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

[image]

what the problem is? `priceMessage` doesn't show me the problem so I can fix it
why it's show a grey line with no red warning?
I tried to figure what's happening nothing work

so what's wrong with `priceMessage`?

```
private int calculatePrice() {
    int price = quantity * 5;
    return price;}


public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int Price=calculatePrice();
    String priceMessage = " total "+ Price;
    priceMessage = priceMessage + "\n Thank you";
    displayMessage(priceMessage);}



private void displayMessage(String message) {
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
  priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(message));
}
```

Comment: Thats not an error. You probably had highlighted `priceMessage` and it underlined all instances of that variable (then got stuck) Just restart intelliJ to fix it. EDIT: this is wrong, check answer

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" is documented [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000395439-Underlined-variables-)

This is because you are reassigning the variable `priceMessage`. This is not an issue and you don't need to be worried.

EDIT: However, there are instances that you want to avoid reassigning variables, where it would hide errors.

Comment: but when i tried to run the android app the button submitOrder crashed and like i said there is no red warning

Comment: did you get any error message? Not getting a red squiggly doesn't mean your program is correct

Comment: oh that's right, there is a mistake but turns out the underline got nothing to do with it so thanks, i just panicked